# RandR extension missing

Tags: xorg, tightvncserver

When I try to run xrandr on Ubuntu 17.10 (artful) with xfce 4.12 over VNC I get the error

```
RandR extension missing
```

I've tried installing libxrandr2 but it's already installed.  When I run lxrandr I get the error:

```
Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
```

I'm using tightvnc as the VNC server.  I've tried all the usual sudo apt-get repair things.

When I do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
```

I'm told that the package is already the newest version.

Answer (score 3):

you have to set display size before starting the vnc
like `vncserver -geometry 1920x1080 :1`

Answer (score -3):

Try installing the development version of randr:

```
sudo apt-get install libxrandr-dev
```